# How to programmatically set up Doctrine entity listener in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Symfony 3.4 app and a Composer package with an `EntityChangeListener` to log entity property changes. The package also contains a `EntityListenerPass` (compiler pass) which iterates over a list of class names defined in app `config.yml` while building the service container. It programmatically tags the entity classes like this to notify the listener on `preUpdate` events:

```
$listener = $container->getDefinition('entity_history.listener.entity_change');
$entities = $container->getExtensionConfig('entity_history')[0]['entities'];

foreach ($entities as $className) {
    $listener->addTag('doctrine.orm.entity_listener', ['entity' => $className, 'event' => 'preUpdate']);
}
```

Adding those tags causes a lot of errors which appear unrelated. In example undefined index errors inside the Doctrine UnitOfWork for the entity states. Also related entities which are loaded from database suddenly are recognised as *new* by Doctrine. Even object comparison inside a `switch` statement started to fail with:

> Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?

But without those listeners, everything works fine and all tests pass. Is there an alternative/better way to programmatically set up Doctrine entity listeners?

Comment: could you give link to `EntityChangeListener` ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what link you exactly mean.

Comment: `EntityChangeListener` this is some bundle ? Because I did not find this in git

Comment: Ah, that listener is from my own bundle which I was developing.

Comment: Very cool. Do you have plans to make a bandle on this basis

Comment: No, it is a corporate project for internal use in a very specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can attach entity listeners by acting directly on the class metadata. In my application (Symfony 2.8), I am doing this for some entities that are marked in my config by adding a listener that reacts to the [`loadClassMetadata`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) event.

With this approach, you can hook your entity listeners when Doctrine loads for the first time the classmetada (by using [`addEntityListener`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html#_addEntityListener)). Thus, you only hook entity listeners that are needed for the current context, nothing more.

Here is a modified version of the listener I use to mirror how it could look in your particular case:

```
namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class MappingListener
{
    private $listenerClassname;
    private $entities;

    public function __construct($listenerClassname, array $entities)
    {
        $this->entities = $entities;
        $this->listenerClassname = $listenerClassname;
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        if(!in_array($classMetadata->name, $this->entities))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Hook the entity listener in the class metadata
        // $classMetadata->addEntityListener( string $eventName, string $class, string $method )
        $classMetadata->addEntityListener('preUpdate', $this->listenerClassName, 'preUpdate');
    }
}
```

And then in your `services.yml`, something like this:

```
mapping.listener:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\MappingListener
    arguments: [ "%your_listener_classname%", "%your_entities_array%" ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata, lazy: true }
```

Comment: Thanks. Because my actual listener requires a service to be injected I changed the compiler pass to get the definition of `doctrine.orm.default_entity_listener_resolver` and add a method call to register my `EntityChangeListener` as a service. Otherwise the `ContainerAwareEntityListenerResolver` would plainly and incorrectly instantiate the listener.